# Typescript says array.pop() might return undefined even when array is guaranteed to contain elements

Tags: arrays, typescript

Why does Typescript warn me that `pop()` might return `undefined` even after I've verified that I'm removing an element from a non-empty array?

```js
type Person = {
  name: string;
};

const people: Person[] = [{ name: 'Sandra' }];

if (people.length) {
  const { name } = people.pop();
  // TS Error: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Person | undefined'.
}
```

Even if I make the guarantee more explicit, I get the same error:

```js
if (people.length > 0 && people[people.length - 1] !== undefined){
  const { name } = people.pop();
  // TS Error: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Person | undefined'.
}
```

Comment: TS is unable to make decision which is based on boolean coersion in this particular case

Comment: I added an edit to show that even without type coercion, I still get the error.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

See [microsoft/TypeScript#30406](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30406) for a canonical answer.

---

For the question, "why does the compiler think that `pop()` might return `undefined` even when I check the array's `length`", the short answer is "because the TypeScript standard library's [call signature for the `pop()` method on `Array<T>`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ea93ee6db9441eb51a1d816e114b0468363dcd9c/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1236) returns `T | undefined`":

```
interface Array<T> {
  // ... elided
  pop(): T | undefined;
  // ... elided
}
```

Thus whenever you call `pop()` on an array, the type of the return value will include `undefined`.

---

The logical next question is "why don't they make better call signatures which return `T` if the `length` is nonzero and `undefined` if the `length` is zero?"  The answer to *that* is "because checking the `length` property of a general array type doesn't change the apparent type of the array, so the call signatures can't tell the difference".

You could, for example, add a few call signatures like this:

```
interface Array<T> {
  pop(this: { length: 0 }): undefined;
  pop(this: { 0: T }): T;
}
```

By using [`this` parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters), each call signature will only be selected when the array on which the method is called matches the specified type.  If the array has a `length` of `0`, return `undefined`.  If the array has an element of type `T` at the key `0`, return `T`.

This will work well for [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) types whose length is fixed and whose element indices are known:

```
declare const u: [];
const a = u.pop(); // undefined

declare const v: [1, 2];
const b = v.pop(); // 1 | 2
```

But of course calling `pop()` on a tuple is a bad idea and not the kind of thing you'd be likely to want. If you have a variable-length array and call `pop()` on it, neither call signature is selected and you fall back to the built-in `T | undefined`, even if you try to check the `length`:

```
const w = Math.random() < 0.5 ? [] : ["a"] // string[]
if (w.length) {
  w.pop().toUpperCase(); // error! Object is possibly undefined
}
```

The problem is that the `length` property of an `Array<T>` is of type `number`, and there's no "nonzero `number`" type to narrow `w.length` to.  In order to support this kind of thing, you'd need something like [negated types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4196) which are not part of TypeScript.  It's possible that with sufficient compiler work, someone could give enough structure to arrays in TypeScript that a truthiness check on `w.length` would narrow down the type of the array to something you can call `pop()` on without worrying about getting `undefined` out.

But it would add a ton of complexity to the compiler and the language to support this use case.  The benefit is not likely to outweigh the cost.

---

In the absence of this, it's so much easier for you to skip the `length` check and just call `pop()`, checking to see whether it's `undefined` or not.  This is the same amount of work for *you*, since it's just moving the check from before to after the call, and it makes things more straightforward for the *compiler*.

The other answers posted here suggest this and other workarounds, so I won't go into them.  My main point is that the language is just not equipped to allow a `length` check to affect the behavior of `pop()`.  Or, as @RyanCavanaugh (dev lead of TS) [commeted in microsoft/TypeScript#30406](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30406#issuecomment-473037675),

> This isn't something we're capable of tracking

Oh well!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.1.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJSnAngHgCoB8yA3gFDLIAOA9pQBRgAWwAzgFwnIA2EIA5kw4AGZAF8AlBwCuIACYQYoCLIDc5KrQbN2nIRzxjJyPGtGlS8hFzhQUCaiBZhkUjgG0AumvuPncZAC8LgB0NPTiKsgA9FEucgpKsuaW1rbIPk7IAG7uAIwANMgATF6kGc4ARoHZoZoR0bG5yAA+xeblyADu1QCycEzBmHLUALZ04sg4yELBAKzIAPzInsjuAERwax4NyE5QoHyepMAwyHSdwTz8TBNkFBdh48Fg1ACqlJTQAMJwLBDjkRiyGgUGoUAAhMgAPIVABWEAQzlYGhYLGAFS4WDi8kUIGUpFEyFIQA)

Comment: Yeah, they are "not capable of tracking" but still claim that TS is a "superset" of JS. Oh, well.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way.

```
type Person = {
  name: string;
};

const people: Person[] = [{ name: 'Sandra' }];

if (people.length) {
  const nextPerson = people.pop() ;
   if(nextPerson){
    const {name} =nextPerson;
   }
  
}
```

**Solution-2 (! after pop)**

```
type Person = {
      name: string;
    };
    
    const people: Person[] = [{ name: 'Sandra' }];
    
    if (people.length) {
        const {name}=people.pop()!;
        console.log(name);
    
      
    }
```

Comment: Hey so, I really like this pop()! strategy, gonna go look at the spec, but just curious what that does?

Comment: Love the pop()!

Comment: Wow, TIL `pop()!`

Answer (score 3):

You can either use "as" keyword or "!" to asser that array.pop() is not returning non-null or non-undefined values.

```js
// We are telling the compiler that the returned value will always be a string
if (people.length) {
  const { name } = people.pop() as string;
}

// We are telling compiler that the value will never be null or undefined 
if (people.length) {
  const { name } = people.pop()!;
}
```

[for more information](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `as` keyword to assert that the pop() is returning a string like this:

```js
if (people.length) {
  const { name } = people.pop() as string;
}
```

This tells Typescript pop() is returning a string and not undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use `pop()` and check the existence of value. The `pop` method returns `undefined` when the array is empty.

```
type Person = {
    name: string;
};

const people: Person[] = [{ name: 'Sandra' }];

let person = people.pop();
if (person) {
    const { name } = person;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
type Person = {
  name: string;
};

const people: Person[] = [{ name: 'Sandra' }];

if (people.length) {
    let popped = people.pop();
    console.log(popped);
}
```

Output:

```
[LOG]: {
  "name": "Sandra"
}
```

It solves the problem, then you can get the name. But it could be that typescript couldn't map the returned value to the object { name }

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question as asked, which is about the behavior of the TypeScript compiler and not about the runtime behavior of JavaScript.