# How do you tackle the following error in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript and started learning it because everyone seems to be super adamant on coding in typescript over `js`. So, to give it a shot, I thought I would start with applying `ts` to simple data structure problems. But I am getting stuck on the following things that I just don't seem to get.

```
interface GraphType {
  [index: string]: string[];
}

const graph: GraphType = {
  a: ['c', 'b'],
  b: ['d'],
  c: ['e'],
  d: ['f'],
  e: [],
  f: []
}

const depthFirstPrint = (graph: GraphType, source: string) => {
  const stack: string[] = [source];
  
  while(stack.length > 0) {
    const current: string = stack.pop(); // <1>
    console.log(current);
    for (let neighbor of graph[current]) { //<2>
      stack.push(neighbor);
    }
  }
};

depthFirstPrint(graph, 'a'); //abdfce
```

Its showing error on: 
`<1>` saying `Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'` 
Which is pretty confusing since I declare `stack` to be `string[]` i.e. `array of strings` AND I am checking to see if the array `stack` isn't empty with `while(stack.length > 0)`. 
`<2>` saying `Object is possibly 'undefined'` and I am not sure exactly how to handle this. Cos in `js` if its `undefined` then the `for` loop won't execute and that is the desirable behavior. But I don't know how to handle this in `ts`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript says array.pop() might return undefined even when array is guaranteed to contain elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65514481/typescript-says-array-pop-might-return-undefined-even-when-array-is-guaranteed)

Comment: @Joe Thanks for the reply. So `<1>` seems to be an issue with the compiler and I guess I would have to use the `!` operator after `stack.pop()`, which I find very ugly. Do you have an answer or suggestion for what needs to be done for `<2>`. Btw, Thanks for that link, it was very helpful.

Comment: Do you have some unusual settings in your tsconfig? I tried pasting your code into TS Playground https://www.typescriptlang.org/play and only got error `<1>`, not error `<2>`.

Comment: @pandubear Thanks for the reply. I don't think so. I have `target:ES2020`, `module: commonjs`, `moduleResolution: node`, `strict: true` and everything under the `additionalChecks` to true (which could be something to look at I guess). The `noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature: true` is the one that caught my attention now, since you mentioned it. Is that it? I don't really know what it does, but I like to have my tsconfig to as strict as possible, so made all of those `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you've checked `stack.length > 0` in `while` but how compiler would know `stack.pop()` always has value?

For example let say `stack.length` is `1` and `while(stack.length > 0)` is true but in below code `current1` and `current2` is undefined while `stack.length` is greater than `1`:

```
while(stack.length > 0) {
    const current = stack.pop(); 
    const current1 = stack.pop(); 
    const current2 = stack.pop(); 
}
```

**Solution**

You can define `current` as `string | undefined` but before use the variable you need to check that to see if it has value or not:

```
const depthFirstPrint = (graph: GraphType, source: string) => {
  const stack: string[] = [source];
  
  while(stack.length > 0) {
    const current = stack.pop(); // <1>
    console.log(current);

    if(current)
      for (let neighbor of graph[current]) { //<2>
         stack.push(neighbor);
      }
  }
};
```

Here is working sample: [PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&ssl=26&ssc=3&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOJTgBwBYBUCemKA3gFDLIDaoAJhAB4BcyAzmFKAOYC6zbHITpW4BuUgF9SpBAHsQbZJww5m6LHkIoAvMjIU4zSgHIERgDTIjAIyPcz5ZFcNGat%20xQTOIbhzWcwfCghDOwcYEIkpWXkwZDpMMGwAMWAoNgAFAVidAAoldVVlDSILFhkAVygkPnYuAEpkLQA%20XQdohTZEAGsagSFuRqoyyqRRBwcAd2xgABsIHM6ELoA6OcFE5BaABga9CmR22IRKqAhwQcWVzBlMHLqRZAB6R%20QAHgBGJocPOTK51ZknByxygp3A9yk%202QwBgwJOZzAdW%20%20xgMigyByc1iIAgwE42CsaOQMhgiiKlBBYLA3F2T0erwATF8oSzLstMOUWNgcji8QS0RCWchJBRJOIxKR4okUmkwJlQGA8kULEY4EZ7nS4FYaDAkEA)

**Update based on OP's comment:**

If you want to turn on `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` in your `TSConfig` you just need more checking :) like this:

```
while(stack.length > 0) {
    const current = stack.pop(); // <1>
    console.log(current);
    
    if(current) {
    let value = graph[current];
    
      if(value)
        for (let neighbor of value) { //<2>
           stack.push(neighbor);
        }
    }
  }
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=6&ssl=29&ssc=4&pln=17&pc=3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOJTgBwBYBUCemKA3gFDLIDaoAJhAB4BcyAzmFKAOYC6zbHITpW4BuUgF9SpBAHsQbZJww5m6LHkIoAvMjIU4zSgHIERgDTIjAIyPcz5ZFcNGat%20xQTOIbhzWcwfCghDOwcYEIkpWXkwZDpMMGwAMWAoNgAFAVidAAoldVVlDSILFhkAVygkPnYuAEpkLQA%20XQdohTZEAGsagSFuRqoyyqRRBwcAd2xgABsIHM6ELoA6OcFE5BaABga9CmR22IRKqAhwQcWVzBlMHLqRZAB6R%20QAHgBGJocPOTK51ZknByxygp3A92%20yEhwBgwJOZzAu0hc1iADc4DNytpFEVKCCwWAxvsocSKDCcujMRA6pDiTAZFBkDkUcgQBBgJxsFYGcgZDBkJSsbsno9XgAmL6kqWXZaYcosbA5NkcrkMiFSiiSYla5CScRiUjxRIpNJgTKgMB5IoWIxwIz3EVwKw0GBIIA)

Comment: @Vaibhav_M Has your problem been solved? let me know if there is a problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sry I had something come up and got tied up. The issue still persist with `<2>` and I get `Object is possibly undefined`. I checked on @pandubear's suggestion and it is the `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` that is raising that issue when enabled. And you can replicate it in the playground too. And as I told him `I don't really know what it does, but I like to have my tsconfig to as strict as possible, so made all of those to true`. What do you think I should do. And do you know what that option is useful for. Thanks again.

Comment: @Vaibhav_M Have you checked the playground link in my answer? I can't see any issue

Comment: As I said, If you turn on the `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` in the TSConfig (under Type Checking) of the Playground, It starts giving that error (for the same code). And I have that turned on in the TSConfig of my project, so I don't know what to do in that case. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Vaibhav_M I update my answer and also I put working sample link in my answer. you just need some more `if`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Very sorry as I again got caught up in something and couldn't come back to check the site. Ofcourse I will accept the ans as it answers all my questions. Thanks again for all your time and effort in helping me.