# Typescript cant determine type of callback function correctly

Tags: javascript, typescript

After running this typescript code it gives me an error on the item parameter of a callback function.Can't find what the problem is

```
function tap<T>(array:T[],callback:(array:T[])=> T ):T{
    return callback(array)
}


const myResult = tap<number>([1,2,3,4],(item)=>{
    if(item.length !==0 ){
        return item.pop()
    }else{
        return 1
    }

})
```

error output

```
Argument of type '(item: number[]) => (() => number | undefined) | 10' is not assignable to parameter of type '(array: number[]) => number'.
  Type '(() => number | undefined) | 10' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    Type '() => number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but Array.pop() returns undefined when the array is empty. You've already had an if condition statement, so I don't get why.BTW `<number>item.pop();` works.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65514481/typescript-says-array-pop-might-return-undefined-even-when-array-is-guaranteed

Comment: `return item.pop()!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`item.pop()` might return undefined. You can modify the callback function to

```
const myResult = tap<number>([1,2,3,4], (item) => {
    return item.pop() ?? 1;
})
```

If the array was empty and `pop()` returned `undefined` the callback function will return 1.

Answer (score 2):

Its complaining that the item could be undefined.  Just change tap to tap<number | undefined>

```
function tap<T>(array: T[], callback: (array: T[]) => T): T {
  return callback(array);
}

const myResult = tap<number | undefined>([1, 2, 3, 4], (item) => {
  if (item.length !== 0) {
    return item.pop();
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would guess your error is here

```js
return item.pop()
```

item.pop() can potentially return 'undefined'. That is why you are returning 'number | undefined'.

I believe it could work like this

```js
function tap<T>(array:T[],callback:(array:T[])=> T ):T{
  return callback(array)
}


const myResult = tap<number>([1,2,3,4],(item)=>{
  if(item.length !==0 ){
      return item.pop()!
  }
  return 1
})
```

I simply added '!' at the end of pop() :-)

that is telleing typescript that it can safely trust your code and that you will indeed never return an undefined value. Since you have a condition checking the behaviour of the code, you can safely add the '!'.

I would not recommend adding this without a check, though.

Cheers!

Comment: That's pretty sweet!  Had no idea about this ts functionality.  Thanks for the enlightenment!

Comment: My pleasure! Use it with caution though. Using the '!' sign in an abusive matter could result in the crash of your app since typescript will not get what is expected.

Comment: Yeah for sure.  Seems a little hacky but a cool trick none the less - especially for those instances you are doing checks but ts is complaining about types anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I find another approach. as pop on the empty array will return undefined we must tell write all possible cases. This will solve the problem

`

```
function tap<T>(array:T[],callback:(array:T[])=> T ):T{
    return callback(array)
}


const myResult = tap<number>([1,2,3,4],(item)=>{
        return item.pop() || 1
})
```

`